# Bash substring with regular expression

Tags: linux, bash, substring

In a bash script, I´d like to extract a **variable** string from a given string. I mean, i´d like to extract the string `file.txt` from the string:

```
This is the file.txt from my folder.
```

I tried:

```
var=$(echo "This is the file.txt from my folder.")
var=echo ${var##'This'}
...
```

but I´d like to make it in a cleaner way, using the `expr`, `sed` or `awk` commands.

Thanks

**Edited:**

I found another way (nevertheless, the answer with the sed command is the best one for me):

```
var=$(echo 'This is the file.txt from my folder.')
front=$(echo 'This is the ')
back=$(echo ' from my folder.')
var=${var##$front}
var=${var%$back} 
echo $var
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The following solution uses `sed` with `s/` (substitution) to remove the leading and trailing parts:

```
echo "This is the file.txt from my folder." | sed "s/^This is the \(.*\) from my folder.$/\1/"
```

Output:

```
file.txt
```

The `\(` and `\)` enclose the part which we want to keep. This is called a group. Because it's the first (and only) group which we use in this expression, it's group 1. We later reference this group inside of the replacement string with `\1`.

The `^` and `$` signs make sure that the complete string is matched. This is only necessary for the special case that the filename contains either `"from my folder."` or `"This is the"`.

Answer (score 1):

You could try grep:

```
var=$(egrep -o file.txt)
```

Answer (score 1):

If 'file.txt' is a fixed string, and won't change, then you can do it like this:

`var="This is the file.txt from my folder"`

Notice that you don't need to echo the string to the variable, you just type it on the right side of the binary '=' operator.

`echo $var |sed -e 's/^.*\(file\.txt\).*$/\1/'`

Depending on your sed(1) version, you can loose the escaping of the parenthesis if you have the -r (extended regexp) option in sed(1).

If 'file.txt' changes, than you can create a pattern on a best effort basis, like:

`echo $var |sed -e 's/^.* \([^ ]\+\.[^ ]\+\) .*$/\1/'`

Answer (score 0):

No need to use `sed` or `awk`. Since 2004, bash has built in regex matching with the `=~` operator.

```bash
input="This is the file.txt from my folder."
[[ $input =~ ([[:alnum:]]+\.[[:alnum:]]+) ]]
echo ${BASH_REMATCH[0]}
```

Output:

```
file.txt
```

If you're not comfortable writing Regular Expressions, it's easier to do interactively with regex101. For `bash`, use their default `PCRE` (perl compatible regular expressions) flavor.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

using `gawk` :

```
gawk '_<($_ = RT)' RS='[^ /\0]+[.][^\0/\n ]+'

file.txt
```

`"_"` serves 2 different (implicit) purposes here :

- left  of `<`, it's an empty string `""`
- right of `<`, it's used as numeric zero, yielding `$0`